# Como imprimir apenas números que se repetem entre duas listas diferentes?

Tags: java

Eu tenho duas listas de 50 números.
Uma tem múltiplos de `3` e a outra múltiplos de `7`.

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

List<Long> lista1  = new ArrayList<>();
List <Long> lista2 = new ArrayList<>();

for (long a = 1; a <= 50; a++) {

long b,c; 
b = a*3;
c = a*7;      

  lista1.add(b);
  lista2.add(c); 

      }
    System.out.println("Lista(1)="+lista1);
    System.out.println("Lista(2)="+lista2);
  }
}
```

Veja funcionando no repl:
https://repl.it/repls/TragicSiennaBoolean

Preciso que somente os números que se repetem entre as duas listas seja impresso, sendo assim apenas:

Lista(3)=`[21, 42, 63, 84, 105, 126, 147]`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o método `retainAll(Collection<?> c)`:

```
public class RetainsAll {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Long> lista1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Long> lista2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (long a = 1; a <= 50; a++) {    
            lista1.add(a*3);
            lista2.add(a*7);
        }
        System.out.println("Lista(1) = "+lista1);
        System.out.println("Lista(2) = "+lista2);

        lista1.retainAll(lista2);

        System.out.println("Interseção = " + lista1);
    }
}
```

Observação: esse método vai alterar sua lista. Se você não quer que isso ocorra, crie um cópia defensiva:

```
List<Long> intersecao = new ArrayList<>(lista1);
intersecao.retainAll(lista2);
```

Comment: Tudo bem felipe, não está funcionando no Repl.

Comment: Consegui aqui está certo... mas como faria com Big Integer???

Comment: @William Da mesma forma. Você só teria que mudar sua *List* para `List<BigInteger>` e adicionar os *BigIntegers* para ela.

Comment: Obrigado amigo!

Comment: Olá Felipe Marinho, o único problema é que se os números não estivessem em uma lista, (List) por exemplo, como seria para fazer o mesmo sistema, imprimir apenas os números repetidos de duas formulas diferentes??

Comment: O "retainAll" não funciona apenas para números impressos que não estão dentro de uma lista...

Comment: @William O *retainAll* é um método da *API* de *Collections*. Você pode aplicar essa operação em qualquer coleção que a implemente (*List*, *Set*, *Queue*, etc) de qualquer tipo de elemento (*String*, *Double*, qualquer classe). Se você tem, por exemplo, *arrays* armazenando os valores, bastaria criar qualquer coleção a partir deles e executar o método. Caso você, por algum motivo, queira fazer "no braço", dê uma olhada em como esse método é implementando no `ArrayList` [aqui](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#714).

Comment: Então Felipe, eu postei uma nova pergunta porque não estou conseguindo imprimir sem as listas...

Comment: Tudo bem Felipe, eu postei outra pergunta.. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275985/como-imprimir-apenas-n%C3%BAmeros-que-se-repetem-entre-duas-formulas-diferentes