# Como imprimir apenas números que se repetem entre duas formulas diferentes?

Tags: java

Eu tenho duas formulas de 50 números.
Uma tem múltiplos de `3` e a outra múltiplos de `7`.

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {           
    BigInteger start = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger limit = new BigInteger("50");
    BigInteger n1 = new BigInteger("3");
    BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger("7");

    for (BigInteger a = start; a.compareTo(limit) <= 0; a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {              
        BigInteger copas3 = a.multiply(n1); 
        BigInteger copas7 = a.multiply(n2);

        System.out.println( copas3 );
        System.out.println( copas7 );      
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no repl: https://repl.it/repls/AngryImpureSequences

Preciso que somente os números que se repetem entre as duas formulas sejam impressos.
Sendo assim, apenas:

```
21
42
63
84
105
126
147
```

Comment: Você quer apenas com esses códigos ou podemos sugerir aplicações diferentes?

Comment: Pode ser com aplicações diferentes, mas precisa ser BigInteger e sem Listas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução consideravelmente simples passa por utilizar duas variáveis no `for` uma para o `copas3` e outra para o `copas7`, em vez de ser a variável `a` para as duas. Assim pode ir aumentando sempre a que é mais baixa para dar a possibilidade de ambas serem iguais:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    BigInteger start = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger limit = new BigInteger("50");
    BigInteger n1 = new BigInteger("3");
    BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger("7");

    for (BigInteger a=start,b=start;a.compareTo(limit)<=0 && b.compareTo(limit) <= 0;){ 
        BigInteger copas3 = a.multiply(n1); //contador "a" apenas para o copas3
        BigInteger copas7 = b.multiply(n2); //contador "b" apenas para o copas7

        int comparacao = copas3.compareTo(copas7); 
        if (comparacao == 0) { //escreve apenas se forem iguais
            System.out.println(copas3);
        }

        //aumenta apenas o mais pequeno
        if (comparacao <= 0) { 
            a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
        else {
            b = b.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
    }
}
```

[Veja o resultado que estava a procura no Ideone](https://ideone.com/p1kKI5)

Comment: Olá @Isac tudo bem? Então, o código está bom mas infelizmente não funcionou, não tem uma outra maneira? Quando se tenta fazer uma soma progressiva na formula, por exemplo "2+4+6+8+10+12" não funciona.. lembrando que, 2+2+2+2+2+2.. = (2,4,6,8,10,12) 
é diferente de 2+4+6+8+10+12 = (2,6,12,20,30,42).

Comment: @William Se apenas precisa de somar os que são iguais nos dois é uma questão de colocar a soma só dentro do `if (comparacao == 0) {`. Se não for isso, infelizmente o seu exemplo ficou muito longe do que precisa e dessa forma acabou de ter uma resposta também longe do que precisa. Sugiro assim que torne mais evidente o que está realmente a tentar fazer

Comment: @William E porque não colocou as fórmulas que precisa de facto? Torne a pergunta o mais clara possível incluindo as fórmulas que realmente está a utilizar e o resultado esperado para essas fórmulas.

Comment: Desculpa é que eu pensei que assim daria certo... vc pode me ajudar Isac?? =/

Comment: @William uma vez que a minha resposta responde a 100÷ a esta questão aconselho a finalizar esta questão e abrir uma nova exatamente com as fórmulas que precisa de utilizar e os resultados que tem que dar. Eu responderei a essa pergunta se for evidente o que pretende.

Comment: Tudo bem Isac, eu finalizei e postei outra pergunta... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276084/como-imprimir-apenas-n%C3%BAmeros-que-se-repetem-entre-duas-formulas-progressivas-dif