# Como imprimir apenas números que se repetem entre duas formulas progressivas diferentes?

Tags: java

Eu tenho duas formulas progressivas de 10 números.
Cada uma delas se somará a um determinado número.

A primeira formula progride assim `0+2+4+6+8+10+12+14+16+18+20`.
E seu resultado é (`2,6,12,20,30,42,56,72,90,110`).
Somando esse resultado com um número estabelecido, no caso `"1"`.
Resultado Final será:(`3,7,13,21,31,43,57,73,91,111`).

A segunda formula progride assim `0+4+8+12+16+20+24+28+32+36+40`.
E seu resultado é (`4,12,24,40,60,84,112,144,180,220`).
Somando esse resultado com um número estabelecido, no caso `"3"`.
Resultado Final será:(`7,15,27,43,63,87,115,147,183,223`).

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigInteger start = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger limit = new BigInteger("10");
        BigInteger zap1 = new BigInteger("0");
        BigInteger zap2 = new BigInteger("0");
        BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger("2"); //formula(1) progressiva
        BigInteger n4 = new BigInteger("4"); //formula(2) progressiva
        BigInteger soma1 = new BigInteger("1"); //número(1) estabelecido     
        BigInteger soma2 = new BigInteger("3"); //número(2) estabelecido

for (BigInteger a = start; a.compareTo(limit) <= 0; a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {

zap1 = zap1.add(n2.multiply(a));  //formula(1) progressiva
zap2 = zap2.add(n4.multiply(a));  //formula(2) progressiva          

BigInteger copas1 = zap1.add(soma1);  //Resultado final(1)
BigInteger copas2 = zap2.add(soma2);  //Resultado final(2)

        System.out.println( copas1 );
        System.out.println( copas2 );       

          }
      }
```

Veja funcionando no repl: https://repl.it/repls/PeacefulOvalPhases

Resultado final da primeira formula: (`3,7,13,21,31,43,57,73,91,111`).
Resultado final da segunda formula: (`7,15,27,43,63,87,115,147,183,223`).

Comparando os resultados finais das duas formulas vemos que os números repetidos são:
O `7` e `43`.

Portanto a saída do programa deveria imprimir apenas:

```
7
43
```

Importante frisar que: Não pode ser em `ArrayList`, e os números precisam ser `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando a mesma técnica que utilizei na [sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275985/como-imprimir-apenas-n%C3%BAmeros-que-se-repetem-entre-duas-formulas-diferentes/275995#275995) consegue chegar ao resultado pretendido. A técnica passa por utilizar duas variáveis de incremento, uma para cada formula. E com estas incrementar apenas a mais pequena e ir comparando:

```
BigInteger start = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger limit = new BigInteger("10");
BigInteger zap1 = new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger zap2 = new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger("2"); // formula(1) progressiva
BigInteger n4 = new BigInteger("4"); // formula(2) progressiva
BigInteger soma1 = new BigInteger("1"); // número(1) estabelecido
BigInteger soma2 = new BigInteger("3"); // número(2) estabelecido

for (BigInteger a = start, b=start; a.compareTo(limit) <= 0 && b.compareTo(limit) <= 0;) {

    //comparação agora com a logica de ambas as formulas
    int comparacao = zap1.add(soma1).compareTo(zap2.add(soma2));

    if (comparacao == 0 && zap1.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0 && zap2.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) != 0) {
        System.out.println(zap1.add(soma1));
    }

    //aumenta apenas o mais pequeno
    if (comparacao <= 0) {      
        zap1 = zap1.add(n2.multiply(a)); // formula(1) progressiva
        a = a.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    else {      
        zap2 = zap2.add(n4.multiply(b)); // formula(2) progressiva
        b = b.add(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
}
```

Note que o resultado obtido é na verdade:

```
7
43
```

E não apenas o `7` como tinha indicado.

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/s3ndct)

Comment: Muito obrigado Isac... Era simplesmente isso... Funcionou desta vez...